# Prevent that browser loads a site from cache which is protected by basic authentication

Tags: server, apache2, browser, apache2.4

Is there a way to configure Apache 2.4.7 such that when I query a HTML file which is protected by basic authentication the browser doesn't load parts of the site he has already in the cache?

I'm looking for a way that the user sees each time a blank background when he query the HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ctlr+F5` to reload page , Apache will send all of contents.
And also apache has a bit cache on memory . You can try `echo 3 /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

Comment: I'm looking for a way that a user whenever he connects new/again to the html page there is a blank background until he entered a valid password and username. The user shouldn't think about `ctrl+F5` and `echo 3 /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` will only once clear the cache on the server.

Comment: U can use method `clearstatcache() ` in php . That's all I know.